# Is it possible to generate(mine) a block with specific transaction via bitcoin-cli on regtest?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory

I want to generate a block with specific transaction via bitcoin-cli on regtest.

The "generate" command does not have the option. It collects transactions in mempool by the default rule.

I guess I can do it with some code change like the following way but I don't want to change it if possible.

```
TestChain100Setup::CreateAndProcessBlock(const std::vector<CMutableTransaction>& txns, const CScript& scriptPubKey)
{
    const CChainParams& chainparams = Params();
    std::unique_ptr<CBlockTemplate> pblocktemplate = BlockAssembler(chainparams).CreateNewBlock(scriptPubKey);
    CBlock& block = pblocktemplate->block;

    // Replace mempool-selected txns with just coinbase plus passed-in txns:
    block.vtx.resize(1);
    for (const CMutableTransaction& tx : txns)
        block.vtx.push_back(MakeTransactionRef(tx));
```

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.17.1/src/miner.cpp#L147
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.17.1/src/test/test_bitcoin.cpp#L155
https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/generating/generate/

Answer (score 2):

When you run [`generate`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/generating/generate/), it mines a block with the transactions in the mempool:

```
generate nblocks ( maxtries )

Mine up to nblocks blocks immediately (before the RPC call returns) to an address in the wallet.
```

If you want those new coins to be mined to a specific address, you can use [`generatetoaddress`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/generating/generatetoaddress/)

You can create transactions and submit them to the mempool either using the wallet RPC, e.g. [`sendtoaddress`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/sendtoaddress/) or using the rawtransactions RPC:
e.g.

1. [`createrawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/)
2. [`signrawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/rawtransactions/signrawtransaction/)
3. [`sendrawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/rawtransactions/sendrawtransaction/)

`sendrawtransaction` will put the transaction in the mempool, which can then be included in the next block using `generate`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I wanted to know how to include a specific transaction in the next block. e.g. There are txA and txB in mempool now. In this case, I want to include only txA in the next block. Not txB.

Answer (score 0):

In the addPackageTxs func https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ef70f9b52b851c7997a9f1a0834714e3eebc1fd8/src/miner.cpp#L306

```
while (mi != mempool.mapTx.get<ancestor_score>().end() || !mapModifiedTx.empty())
{
    // First try to find a new transaction in mapTx to evaluate.
    if (mi != mempool.mapTx.get<ancestor_score>().end() &&
            SkipMapTxEntry(mempool.mapTx.project<0>(mi), mapModifiedTx, failedTx)) {
        ++mi;
        continue;
    }
```

you can modify the while loop and select which transation index should you include in block.

ex: you can skip transactions which are in mempool within 2 seconds before current time

```
while (mi != mempool.mapTx.get<entry_time>().end() || !mapModifiedTx.empty())
{
    CTxMemPool::txiter iter = mempool.mapTx.project<0>(mi);
    auto time_now = GetTime();

    if (time_now - iter->GetTime() < 2){
       continue;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a prioritize transaction RPC which does this without modifying the binary.